# wxPython - Showing logo while importing

Tags: python, wxpython

I am running a wxPython application that does a lot of modules and packages importing at the beginning and gathering information about the computer (network interfaces, internet connection..) so it takes time, and I'm showing a logo in that time until it ends. the problem is that the logo crashes if you press on it (because the importing are on the MainThread and the GUI can't respond to events), How can I show a logo while importing without letting the GUI crash? (I don't want to let the user to click on the Logo anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by Tim Roberts in this [wxPython-users thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/wxpython-users/b1-POONqceQ/jHcexiSMzssJ) I first tried to spin off the splash screen in a separate thread, which did not work (wxwidgets complains it it not in the main thread). So I did the only obvious thing which I should have done in the first place: make the long running at startup a separate thread.

Side effect: As the splash screens now can react to events, it will disappear when clicked on.

```
import wx

class long_running(object):
    def __init__(self):
        bitmap = wx.EmptyBitmap(300, 150, 127)

        self.mainframe = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'mainframe')
        self.splash = wx.SplashScreen(bitmap, wx.SPLASH_TIMEOUT, 20000, self.mainframe)


    def start(self):
        import time

        # mimicking something taking very long time on startup
        for i in range(20):
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print i
        wx.CallAfter(self.continue_)

    def continue_(self):
        #Destroy the splash screen.
        if self.splash:
            self.splash.Hide()
#             self.splash.Destroy()

        self.mainframe.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import thread
    app = wx.App()

    long_rnn = long_running()

    # Begin loading the application.
    thread.start_new_thread(long_rnn.start, ())
    # Application loaded.

    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In a recent project (on Windows7 and wxPython 2.9.5.1): For displaying a `wx.SplashScreen` while modules are importing we did the following:

We have a main module, which does `import wx` in the beginning, create the `wx.App` and display the splash screen. Only after showing the splash screen we begin to import the "heavy" modules. The very first startup will take 40 seconds. In fact the app will crash if the user clicks on the splash screen. Better said, Windows displays a message box (*EDIT2*) with "Python.exe has stopped working." If the user clicks "Terminate" the app will in fact terminate/crash. If the user does nothing, the app will start up normally. So on Windows there is no "real" crash. It will also not happen when starting the second time (because things are cached)? On subsequent starts startup time is 5 seconds. Sorry, no real answer but too long for a comment also.

*EDIT: Minimum working example added*: Click every one or two seconds on the splash while it is displayed to make Windows show the "Python has stopped working" dialog. The dialog will simply go away when `long_running()` has returned.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def long_running():
    import time
    time.sleep(10)

    # does not show "Python ... stopped working ..."
    #for _ in range(20):
    #    time.sleep(0.5)
    #    wx.Yield()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import wx
    app = wx.App()

    bitmap = wx.EmptyBitmap(300, 150, 127)

    splash = wx.SplashScreen(bitmap, wx.SPLASH_TIMEOUT, 20000, None)

    # Begin loading the application.
    long_running()
    # Application loaded.

    #Destroy the splash screen.
    splash.Hide()
    splash.Destroy()

    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Added a minimum example and a partial solution. Partial, because you will normally not be able to split your task up to ``wx.Yield()`` in between.

Comment: Cross-linked to [wxPython-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/b1-POONqceQ).

Comment: I assume you mean "has stopped working" rather than "has started working".